# GIT - Way to track file changes in your team and warn about potential conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, collaboration, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I am looking for a way/tool to to get notified if someone else on my team is editing the same file as I am. This is in order to prevent conflicts when merging later. It's not about locking the file, but only about turning your attention to it (and then starting a conversation with the other developer if necessary).

And no, I don't think the solution would be better team communication. Regardless of how good your team communication is, there are always cases where you need to make a few changes to various files while working on the "agreed" files. It would not be all that productive if every ten minutes you shout out to everyone "hey, is anyone making changes to that-and-that file?"...

A process/tool like this will improve our productivity by:

- avoiding unnecessary questions ("anyone changing this file?")
- avoiding code conflicts and difficult merges
- not wasting time to refactor the same file that someone else is refactoring

(I have searched but haven't been able to find an answer. Related question: https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/git-way-to-track-file-changes-in-your-team-and-warn-about-potential-conflicts)

Comment: It's not clear if you're asking recommendations for existing tools - in which case, you should ask [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) - or a specific `git` command - in which case you might look into different git workflows, like gitflow, etc. Please edit your question to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I am looking for any way to achieve this, or even just some ideas. I don't think it can be done simply with a git command or gitflow. It involves monitoring, communicating status, comparing the status of multiple machines and sending notifications. The solution probably involves a server side as well. Thanks for recommending that site, I will look into it.

Comment: No problem, but your question is misleading then, because it shouldn't have "GIT" in the title, nor in the tags.

Comment: "it shouldn't have "GIT" in the title, nor in the tags" yes it should. If there is some tool to check everyone's modified files (unpushed commits or locally changed files) and report that to the other user modifying this file git would be relevant since it tracks which files have been changed already. Well I guess if some other tool can do that without the help of git that would also be a good answer. Git is pretty much the point of this question, to avoid conflicts.